# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session . For a Testcase JUnit

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, junit, mockmvc

I have two controllers which are given below, I've been trying to write test cases for both of them but since the controllers user @AuthenticationPrincipal. I am having a hard time writing the test case for them and been getting a error while running the test case .

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/view/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
public ResponseEntity renderDocument(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal, @PathVariable("id") Long id)
        throws IOException {
    Journal journal = journalRepository.findOne(id);
    Category category = journal.getCategory();
    CurrentUser activeUser = (CurrentUser) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();
    User user = userRepository.findOne(activeUser.getUser().getId());
    List<Subscription> subscriptions = user.getSubscriptions();
    Optional<Subscription> subscription = subscriptions.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getCategory().getId().equals(category.getId())).findFirst();
    if (subscription.isPresent() || journal.getPublisher().getId().equals(user.getId())) {
        File file = new File(PublisherController.getFileName(journal.getPublisher().getId(), journal.getUuid()));
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(IOUtils.toByteArray(in));
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/publisher/publish")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('PUBLISHER')")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("category")Long categoryId, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {

    CurrentUser activeUser = (CurrentUser) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();
    Optional<Publisher> publisher = publisherRepository.findByUser(activeUser.getUser());

    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    File dir = new File(getDirectory(publisher.get().getId()));
    createDirectoryIfNotExist(dir);

    File f = new File(getFileName(publisher.get().getId(), uuid));
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
            FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), stream);
            stream.close();
            Journal journal = new Journal();
            journal.setUuid(uuid);
            journal.setName(name);
            journalService.publish(publisher.get(), journal, categoryId);
            return "redirect:/publisher/browse";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You failed to publish " + name + " => " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty");
    }

    return "redirect:/publisher/publish";
}
```

The Test Case is

```
@Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "user1", roles = { "USER" })
    public void renderDocument() throws Exception {


        mockMvc.perform(get("/view/{id}", 1)).andExpect(content().contentType(contentType)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

But i am getting a following error :-

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at com.crossover.trial.journals.model.Publisher_$$_jvst650_0.toString(Publisher_$$_jvst650_0.java)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.getVariableValueAsString(UriComponents.java:269)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expandUriComponent(UriComponents.java:234)
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents$FullPathComponent.expand(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:685)
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:47)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expand(UriComponents.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.buildAndExpand(UriComponentsBuilder.java:412)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.<init>(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(MockMvcRequestBuilders.java:55)
    at com.crossover.trial.journals.rest.JournalServiceTest.renderDocument(JournalServiceTest.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

JournalServiceTest.java

```
package com.crossover.trial.journals.rest;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.crossover.trial.journals.Application;
import com.crossover.trial.journals.model.Journal;
import com.crossover.trial.journals.model.Publisher;
import com.crossover.trial.journals.model.User;
import com.crossover.trial.journals.repository.PublisherRepository;
import com.crossover.trial.journals.service.JournalService;
import com.crossover.trial.journals.service.ServiceException;
import com.crossover.trial.journals.service.UserService;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class JournalServiceTest {

    private final static String NEW_JOURNAL_NAME = "New Journal";

    @Autowired
    private JournalService journalService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PublisherRepository publisherRepository;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).apply(springSecurity()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void browseSubscribedUser() {
        List<Journal> journals = journalService.listAll(getUser("user1"));
        assertNotNull(journals);
        assertEquals(1, journals.size());

        assertEquals(new Long(1), journals.get(0).getId());
        assertEquals("Medicine", journals.get(0).getName());
        assertEquals(new Long(1), journals.get(0).getPublisher().getId());
        assertNotNull(journals.get(0).getPublishDate());
    }

    @Test
    public void browseUnSubscribedUser() {
        List<Journal> journals = journalService.listAll(getUser("user2"));
        assertEquals(0, journals.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void listPublisher() {
        User user = getUser("publisher1");
        Optional<Publisher> p = publisherRepository.findByUser(user);
        List<Journal> journals = journalService.publisherList(p.get());
        assertEquals(2, journals.size());

        assertEquals(new Long(1), journals.get(0).getId());
        assertEquals(new Long(2), journals.get(1).getId());

        assertEquals("Medicine", journals.get(0).getName());
        assertEquals("Test Journal", journals.get(1).getName());
        journals.stream().forEach(j -> assertNotNull(j.getPublishDate()));
        journals.stream().forEach(j -> assertEquals(new Long(1), j.getPublisher().getId()));

    }

    @Test(expected = ServiceException.class)
    public void publishFail() throws ServiceException {
        User user = getUser("publisher2");
        Optional<Publisher> p = publisherRepository.findByUser(user);

        Journal journal = new Journal();
        journal.setName("New Journal");

        journalService.publish(p.get(), journal, 1L);
    }

    @Test(expected = ServiceException.class)
    public void publishFail2() throws ServiceException {
        User user = getUser("publisher2");
        Optional<Publisher> p = publisherRepository.findByUser(user);

        Journal journal = new Journal();
        journal.setName("New Journal");

        journalService.publish(p.get(), journal, 150L);
    }

    @Test()
    public void publishSuccess() {
        User user = getUser("publisher2");
        Optional<Publisher> p = publisherRepository.findByUser(user);

        Journal journal = new Journal();
        journal.setName(NEW_JOURNAL_NAME);
        journal.setUuid("SOME_EXTERNAL_ID");
        try {
            journalService.publish(p.get(), journal, 3L);
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }

        List<Journal> journals = journalService.listAll(getUser("user1"));
        assertEquals(2, journals.size());

        journals = journalService.publisherList(p.get());
        assertEquals(2, journals.size());
        assertEquals(new Long(3), journals.get(0).getId());
        assertEquals(new Long(4), journals.get(1).getId());
        assertEquals("Health", journals.get(0).getName());
        assertEquals(NEW_JOURNAL_NAME, journals.get(1).getName());
        journals.stream().forEach(j -> assertNotNull(j.getPublishDate()));
        journals.stream().forEach(j -> assertEquals(new Long(2), j.getPublisher().getId()));
    }

    @Test(expected = ServiceException.class)
    public void unPublishFail() {
        User user = getUser("publisher1");
        Optional<Publisher> p = publisherRepository.findByUser(user);
        journalService.unPublish(p.get(), 4L);
    }

    @Test(expected = ServiceException.class)
    public void unPublishFail2() {
        User user = getUser("publisher1");
        Optional<Publisher> p = publisherRepository.findByUser(user);
        journalService.unPublish(p.get(), 100L);
    }

    @Test
    public void unPublishSuccess() {
        User user = getUser("publisher2");
        Optional<Publisher> p = publisherRepository.findByUser(user);
        journalService.unPublish(p.get(), 4L);

        List<Journal> journals = journalService.publisherList(p.get());
        assertEquals(1, journals.size());
        journals = journalService.listAll(getUser("user1"));
        assertEquals(1, journals.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void renderDocument() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/view/{id}", "1"));
    }

    protected User getUser(String name) {
        Optional<User> user = userService.getUserByLoginName(name);
        if (!user.isPresent()) {
            fail("user1 doesn't exist");
        }
        return user.get();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the Code of file JournalServiceTest.java, please also specify line no : :187

Comment: Kindly Check . I have uploaded the code of the entire JournalServiceTest.java

Answer (score 0):

You have fetched objects from database like below,

> Journal journal = journalRepository.findOne(id);
>
> Category category = journal.getCategory();

and somewhere you have used

> category.getId()

**Clarification :** When you have fetched journal object from database, only journal object fetched along with proxy Category object and not the actual category object. So when you are trying to fetch category using journal object, its trying to initialize the proxy category object with actual category object, which requires a db call.

But as journal object may be detached from session, so it says no session.

**Solution :**  You have proxy object, there are many ways to unwrap proxy object

- `categoryProxyObj=entityManager.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class).getPersistenceContext().unproxy(categoryProxyObj);`
- `categoryProxyObj=((SessionImplementor)session).getPersistenceContext().unproxy(categoryProxyObj);`
- `Hibernate.initialize(categoryProxyObj);
  if (categoryProxyObj instanceof HibernateProxy) {
      categoryProxyObj=((HibernateProxy)categoryProxyObj).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
  }`

Whichever method you prefer, you can use.

Or if you don't need category object but just category id, then in Journal

Use

```
private Category category;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
public Category getCategory() {
    return this.category;
}
```

Instead of

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
private Category category;
```